# On a derivation in a Cauchy problem

Tags: real-analysis

I have the differential equation:

$$x''(t) = F(t) -1, \qquad 0<t<T$$

where $F$ is a continuous function. And the initial conditions are

$$x(0) = x'(0) = 0, \qquad x(T) = 5$$

I have written in my notes that through integration we obtain the equation

$$x(t) = \int_0^t (t- \tau)F(\tau) d \tau - t^2/2$$

But I can't re-obtain this result, Integrating the starting equation I obtain:

$$x'(t) = \int_0^t F(\tau) d \tau -t$$ Utilizing the Mean value theorem for integrals I get

$$x'(t) = t F(c(t))  -t$$ where $0<c<t$ and I have written explicitly the dependence of $c$ on $t$, but integrating this another time I do not obtain the equation in my notes, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x(0) = 0$, you have that
$$
x(t) = \int_0^t x'(s)\, ds = 
\int_0^t \left[\int_0^s F(\tau)\, d\tau\right]\, ds - \frac{t^2}{2}\,.
$$
Let us compute the integral at the r.h.s.
Changing the order of integration we get
$$
\int_0^t \left[\int_0^s F(\tau)\, d\tau\right]\, ds
= \int_0^t \left[\int_{\tau}^t F(\tau)\, ds\right]\, d\tau
= \int_0^t (t-\tau) F(\tau)\, d\tau,
$$
hence your formula follows.